# unsigned 12-bit binary addition/sub

Tags: math, binary, bit

I need to do some add/sub with 12-bit unsigned numbers.

For the unsigned 12-bit ints:

```
x = 0111 1000 0101, x = 1925
y = 1011 1100 0100, y = 3012

z = x+y = ?
z = x-y = ?
```

I got 0011 0100 1001 for x + y

but what should I do for x - y?

The answer is negative, which doesn't exist as an unsigned int.

Comment: In the world of unsigned ints, `x - y` where `x < y` is technically an underflow condition. That's true regardless of how many bits represent a number system. If you want to do what a language like C might do, just do the subtraction and ignore any bits higher than the 12th bit. But it's still an underflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert to [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form, then add.

```
x - y = x + y'
```

Where `y'` is two's complement of `y`.

An easy trick for negation with two's complement is to write your number from right to left.  You essentially copy the number.  Write all the zeros until you encounter a 1, and write the 1 too.  Then flip all the remaining digits.

*eg* negating `0110 1000`:

```
0110 1000
---------
      000    copy zeros until first 1
     1000    copy the 1
1001 1000    flip all remaining bits
```

Comment: Why would I do this if the ints are unsigned?

Comment: Because of binary overflow, it doesn't matter.  The 'negative' is designed this way.  So, your integer will overflow to something that doesn't look right, but that is because you subtracted a larger number.  Why would you expect it to make sense to do that with unsigned integers?  Why don't you try it.